# Remove all the namespaces in xml other than replaceall using java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I want to remove all the namespaces in xml document using java, is there a  efficient way to do it other than replace all method?

Thanks in advance.
Sushma.

Comment: Yes, parse the XML into an object tree, remove the namespaces and serialize the XML again. Seriously, what about replace all?

Comment: What are the results?

Comment: Hi,  I'm new to java, can you please explain little briefly..

Answer (score 1):

Removing the namespace declarations using regex processing is probably feasible provided you don't care about the small probability of matching something that isn't actually a namespace declaration (e.g. inside a comment or CDATA section). Removng the prefixes from element and attribute names is more tricky. Why not do it the easy way, using XSLT? It just needs a simple 2-rule stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select=."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

You can add further rules if you find you need to do more than this, e.g. keeping the namespaces on xml:base or xsi:schemaLocation attributes.